# CASE with IN and SELECT subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, case

I want to perform IN statement with a Select subquery in a CASE logic (MySQL dialect's been using)

So the idea of the query is like this:

```
select a.client_id,
(case when a.client_id in (select distinct a.client_id from account a
where a.display_name='b') then '1' else '0' end) as binary
from account a
group by a.client_id
order by a.client_id
```

It shows error, so I'm wondering how it can be replaced and rewritten?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: add case column to group by

Comment: @jpw - No its not same

Comment: @Prdp I see the error now and stand corrected.

Comment: I just deleted my answer because you can not add a subquery to a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `binary` column is neither an aggregate nor a member of `GROUP BY` clause.

You can either copy the `case` into `GROUP BY`, or replace subquery with :

```
SELECT
    a.client_id
,   MAX(CASE WHEN b.client_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as binary
FROM account a
LEFT OUTER JOIN account b
  ON a.client_id=b.client_id AND b.display_name='b'
GROUP BY a.client_id
GROUP BY a.client_id
```

Now that the `CASE` is pushed inside `MAX`, an aggregate function, the check for presence or absence of other clients with display name of `'b'` can be done by checking the results of an outer join.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the subquery at all. Just try this:

```
select a.client_id,
case when a.display_name = 'b' then '1'
else '0' end as binary
from account a
group by a.client_id
order by a.client_id
```